# Joomla!2.5 Toolbar Not Working

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-component

I'm developing the second view of my back end component in Joomla!2.5. The first two screens - the first page where I ***list questions and answers***, and the ***question editing/adding*** page, both work. The third view, supposed to show and add new school subjects to which these questions will be attached to loads like a wonder... But the toolbar doesn't work at all.

All the folders listed below are in the admin folder. Everything is being done trying to follow the MVC standards.

Part of the *views/reforcodigitals/view.html.php* (where it leads into the "Add subject page"):

```
JToolBarHelper::custom('disciplina.add', 'archive', 'archive', 'Disciplinas', false);
```

*views/disciplina/view.html.php*'s toolbar setup:

```
protected function addToolBar(){
    $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
    $input->set('hidemainmenu', true);
    JToolBarHelper::title('Disciplinas');
    JToolBarHelper::save2new('disciplina.save');
    JToolBarHelper::cancel('disciplina.cancel', 'Voltar');
}
```

*views/disciplina/tmpl/edit.php* form set up:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted Access');
JHtml::_('behavior.tooltip');
?>
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_reforcodigital&view=disciplina&layout=edit'); ?>" method="post" name="adminForm" id="adminForm">   
    <fieldset class="adminform">
        <legend>Detalhes</legend>
        <ul class="adminformlist">
            <?php foreach($this->form->getFieldset() as $field): ?>
            <li><?php echo $field->label; echo $field->input; ?></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I'll gladly update with model/controller/helper code if it's needed. I just don't know what could be happening here.

---

**Edit:** I added the following line to my *views/disciplina/edit.php*'s form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="task" value="disciplina.add" />
```

And it now returns me what seems to be a JINVALID_TOKEN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting invalid token error because there is no token field in your form.You can generate token using below code.

```
<?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>
```

Keep the above code inside form and this should work.

Comment: Perfect, it worked. But it showed me another problem; the *delete* and the *cancel* toolbar buttons don't work at all. Saving does exactly what it's meant to.

Comment: @TheGEffect: what is the error?