# Joomla!2.5 Toolbar buttons not working

Tags: php, model-view-controller, joomla, joomla2.5

This question is a "continuation" of [Joomla!2.5 Toolbar Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16796752/joomla2-5-toolbar-not-working), since the correction of an error led to something completely new I can't seem to wrap around my head, since I'm new to Joomla and I got nearly zero training in this new job.

My toolbar in this component has 3 buttons:

*admin/views/disciplinas/view.html.php*

```
protected function addToolBar(){
    $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
    $input->set('hidemainmenu', true);
    JToolBarHelper::title('Disciplinas');
    JToolBarHelper::save2new('disciplinas.save');
    JToolBarHelper::deleteList('', 'disciplinas.delete');
    JToolBarHelper::cancel('disciplinas.cancel', 'Voltar');
}
```

The model *disciplinas* is a simple JAdminForm with no functions other than `getTable` and `getForm`, both seemingly working fine.

When using the toolbar, though, only the `save2new` button works. Both `deleteList`and `cancel` just "reload" the page, when they should respectively delete a register from the list, and come back to *reforcodigitals*.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a disciplinas controller extending JControllerForm?  In 'disciplinas.cancel', the first part of that is a controller name to call and the second part is the task in the controller to execute.  This may just be an empty class for you, but necessary to ensure the correct task is called upon.